# create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, django

After I fill the registration form and click submit this error pops up

> create_user() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 6 were given

and also it doesn't use the validation inside the form in the template

Doesn't check if the username or email are already in the database or even checking if the the passwords are matching or not

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.forms.widgets import PasswordInput, TextInput
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError


class CustomUserCreationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'text'}), min_length=4, max_length=150)
    email = forms.EmailField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'text'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'text'}), min_length=2, max_length=150)
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=TextInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'text'}), min_length=2, max_length=150)
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'password'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=PasswordInput(attrs={'class':'validate','id': 'icon_prefix', 'type': 'password'}))

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data['username'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(username=username)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Username already exists")
        return username

    def clean_first_name(self):
        first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        
        return first_name

    def clean_last_name(self):
        last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        
        return last_name

    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email'].lower()
        r = User.objects.filter(email=email)
        if r.count():
            raise  ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email

    def clean_password2(self):
        password1 = self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2 = self.cleaned_data.get('password2')

        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise ValidationError("Password don't match")

        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = User.objects.create_user(
            self.cleaned_data['username'],
            self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
            self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
            self.cleaned_data['email'],
            self.cleaned_data['password1']
        )
        return user
```

Comment: Shouldn't you be using [positional arguments](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-argument)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[`create_user`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) expects only the username as a positional parameter. All the other data should be passed as keyword arguments.

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
    self.cleaned_data['username'],
    first_name=self.cleaned_data['first_name'],
    last_name=self.cleaned_data['last_name'],
    email=self.cleaned_data['email'],
    password=self.cleaned_data['password1']
)
```